# connecting elements with drawn line

Tags: android, android-layout, android-custom-view, android-drawable

I'm trying to make some view which will allow user to connect some elements with drawn line.

E.g. on image there are a couple of `TextViews`, user draw line from one to another and if it connected correctly (text1 to text3), line will stay.
[image]

Right now I've implemented custom view, it draw line, which follow your finger:

```
public class FingerLineView extends View {
    private final Paint mPaint;
    private float startX;
    private float startY;
    private float endX;
    private float endY;

    public FingerLineView(Context context) {
        this(context, null);
    }

    public FingerLineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
        super(context, attrs);
        mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mPaint.setStyle(Style.STROKE);
        mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    }

    @Override protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);
        canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getAction()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                startX = event.getX();
                startY = event.getY();
                // Set the end to prevent initial jump 
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                endX = event.getX();
                endY = event.getY();
                invalidate();
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
}
```

This is how it works:

[image: Gif]

But I don't know how to correctly "connect" it with view elements like `TextView`.

Should I do it with completely custom view or there are some better ways to do so?

Comment: if you are going to draw some lines, then the text should be drawn too. 
It's possible to detect coordinates of text view and connect line not to textView itself, but to some invisible rectangle located exactly below it on the view where you are drawing

Answer (score 1):

A canvas is more powerful than you maybe know. ;)
Use its `drawText`-method. Great performance, easy to use and 100% customizeable.

**EDIT:**
Here's a small example code, the calculation is just dummy, you have to positionate it where ever you need it:

```
public class FingerLineView extends View {
private final Paint mPaint;
private final Paint mPaintText;
private float startX;
private float startY;
private float endX;
private float endY;

public FingerLineView(Context context) {
    this(context, null);
}

public FingerLineView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
    super(context, attrs);
    mPaint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaint.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
    mPaint.setColor(Color.RED);
    mPaintText = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    mPaintText.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    mPaintText.setTextSize(30);
}

@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
    super.onDraw(canvas);
    canvas.drawLine(startX, startY, endX, endY, mPaint);
    canvas.drawText("TEXT", startX - mPaintText.measureText("TEXT")/2, startY - 30, mPaintText);
    canvas.drawText("TEXT", endX - mPaintText.measureText("TEXT")/2, endY - 30, mPaintText);
}

@Override
public boolean onTouchEvent(@NonNull MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            startX = event.getX();
            startY = event.getY();
            // Set the end to prevent initial jump
            endX = event.getX();
            endY = event.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
            endX = event.getX();
            endY = event.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            endX = event.getX();
            endY = event.getY();
            invalidate();
            break;
    }
    return true;
}
```

}

Comment: You mean, I should drive text inside canvas and then draw a line following user's finger? Could you please provide some example?

Comment: @Alex Yes, that would be the best solution. I will update your code a bit and let you know as soon as I'm done :)

Comment: @Alex Updated my answer. Small reminder: Don't forget that canvas size calculation is always in PIXEL :)

Comment: Thanks! Can you please tell me how can I correctly check if drawn line connects corresponding texts (e.g. text1 to text3, not text2)?

Comment: @Alex Sorry, I don't understand what you need.

Comment: I mean I draw a couple of texts with canvas.drawText() and want user to connect them with drawn line. How can I check if they connected it correctly? Should I do it inside my custom view FingerListView or inside some Activity?